# DevExpress Winforms: why aren't my newly added Labelcontrols showing up?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I've inherited this project that someone started on a while back. It's made with DevExpress for Winforms. He already had a "welcome" page ready, with the "welkom" label and the "ik heb een afspraak" label (top of the 3 bottom ones). I've just started working on it today and can't seem to find out why my newly added Labelcontrols (the 2 bottom ones) aren't showing up when I launch the program/winforms.

Here's an image of how the designer looks:

[image]

Here's the Designer code page (Designer.cs file):

```
    partial class Welcome
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.layoutCtrlMain = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControl();
            this.lblPickupRepair = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl();
            this.lblNoAppointment = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl();
            this.lblAppointment = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl();
            this.lblWelcome = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl();
            this.layoutMain = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlGroup();
            this.emptySpaceItem1 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem();
            this.emptySpaceItem2 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem();
            this.layoutControlItem1 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem();
            this.emptySpaceItem3 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem();
            this.emptySpaceItem4 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem();
            this.emptySpaceItem5 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem();
            this.layoutControlItem2 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem();
            this.emptySpaceItem6 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem();
            this.layoutControlItem4 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem();
            this.layoutControlItem3 = new DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutCtrlMain)).BeginInit();
            this.layoutCtrlMain.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutMain)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem2)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem1)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem3)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem4)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem5)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem2)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem6)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem4)).BeginInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem3)).BeginInit();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // layoutCtrlMain
            // 
            this.layoutCtrlMain.Controls.Add(this.lblPickupRepair);
            this.layoutCtrlMain.Controls.Add(this.lblNoAppointment);
            this.layoutCtrlMain.Controls.Add(this.lblAppointment);
            this.layoutCtrlMain.Controls.Add(this.lblWelcome);
            this.layoutCtrlMain.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
            this.layoutCtrlMain.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.layoutCtrlMain.Name = "layoutCtrlMain";
            this.layoutCtrlMain.OptionsCustomizationForm.DesignTimeCustomizationFormPositionAndSize = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(2218, 466, 859, 400);
            this.layoutCtrlMain.Root = this.layoutMain;
            this.layoutCtrlMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1131, 427);
            this.layoutCtrlMain.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // lblPickupRepair
            // 
            this.lblPickupRepair.Appearance.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblPickupRepair.Appearance.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.lblPickupRepair.Appearance.Image = global::ESC.Intern.Custom.DigRecWF.Reception.Properties.Resources.Webp_net_resizeimage;
            this.lblPickupRepair.Appearance.Options.UseFont = true;
            this.lblPickupRepair.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor = true;
            this.lblPickupRepair.Appearance.Options.UseImage = true;
            this.lblPickupRepair.ImageAlignToText = DevExpress.XtraEditors.ImageAlignToText.LeftCenter;
            this.lblPickupRepair.IndentBetweenImageAndText = 15;
            this.lblPickupRepair.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(355, 309);
            this.lblPickupRepair.Name = "lblPickupRepair";
            this.lblPickupRepair.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(326, 49);
            this.lblPickupRepair.StyleController = this.layoutCtrlMain;
            this.lblPickupRepair.TabIndex = 8;
            this.lblPickupRepair.Text = "Afhaling / herstelling";
            // 
            // lblNoAppointment
            // 
            this.lblNoAppointment.Appearance.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblNoAppointment.Appearance.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.lblNoAppointment.Appearance.Image = global::ESC.Intern.Custom.DigRecWF.Reception.Properties.Resources.Webp_net_resizeimage;
            this.lblNoAppointment.Appearance.Options.UseFont = true;
            this.lblNoAppointment.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor = true;
            this.lblNoAppointment.Appearance.Options.UseImage = true;
            this.lblNoAppointment.ImageAlignToText = DevExpress.XtraEditors.ImageAlignToText.LeftCenter;
            this.lblNoAppointment.IndentBetweenImageAndText = 15;
            this.lblNoAppointment.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(355, 256);
            this.lblNoAppointment.Name = "lblNoAppointment";
            this.lblNoAppointment.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(331, 49);
            this.lblNoAppointment.StyleController = this.layoutCtrlMain;
            this.lblNoAppointment.TabIndex = 7;
            this.lblNoAppointment.Text = "Ik heb geen afspraak";
            this.lblNoAppointment.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.lblNoAppointment_Click);
            // 
            // lblAppointment
            // 
            this.lblAppointment.Appearance.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 21.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblAppointment.Appearance.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
            this.lblAppointment.Appearance.Image = global::ESC.Intern.Custom.DigRecWF.Reception.Properties.Resources.Webp_net_resizeimage;
            this.lblAppointment.Appearance.Options.UseFont = true;
            this.lblAppointment.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor = true;
            this.lblAppointment.Appearance.Options.UseImage = true;
            this.lblAppointment.ImageAlignToText = DevExpress.XtraEditors.ImageAlignToText.LeftCenter;
            this.lblAppointment.IndentBetweenImageAndText = 15;
            this.lblAppointment.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(355, 203);
            this.lblAppointment.Name = "lblAppointment";
            this.lblAppointment.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(315, 49);
            this.lblAppointment.StyleController = this.layoutCtrlMain;
            this.lblAppointment.TabIndex = 5;
            this.lblAppointment.Text = "Ik heb een afspraak";
            this.lblAppointment.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.lblAppointment_Click);
            // 
            // lblWelcome
            // 
            this.lblWelcome.Appearance.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Narrow", 48F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.lblWelcome.Appearance.ForeColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
            this.lblWelcome.Appearance.Options.UseFont = true;
            this.lblWelcome.Appearance.Options.UseForeColor = true;
            this.lblWelcome.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(290, 70);
            this.lblWelcome.Name = "lblWelcome";
            this.lblWelcome.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(396, 75);
            this.lblWelcome.StyleController = this.layoutCtrlMain;
            this.lblWelcome.TabIndex = 4;
            this.lblWelcome.Text = "Welkom bij ESC!";
            // 
            // layoutMain
            // 
            this.layoutMain.EnableIndentsWithoutBorders = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.True;
            this.layoutMain.GroupBordersVisible = false;
            this.layoutMain.Items.AddRange(new DevExpress.XtraLayout.BaseLayoutItem[] {
            this.emptySpaceItem1,
            this.emptySpaceItem2,
            this.layoutControlItem1,
            this.emptySpaceItem3,
            this.emptySpaceItem4,
            this.emptySpaceItem5,
            this.layoutControlItem2,
            this.emptySpaceItem6,
            this.layoutControlItem4,
            this.layoutControlItem3});
            this.layoutMain.Name = "Root";
            this.layoutMain.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1131, 427);
            this.layoutMain.TextVisible = false;
            // 
            // emptySpaceItem1
            // 
            this.emptySpaceItem1.AllowHotTrack = false;
            this.emptySpaceItem1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(678, 0);
            this.emptySpaceItem1.MinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 24);
            this.emptySpaceItem1.Name = "emptySpaceItem1";
            this.emptySpaceItem1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(433, 407);
            this.emptySpaceItem1.SizeConstraintsType = DevExpress.XtraLayout.SizeConstraintsType.Custom;
            this.emptySpaceItem1.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            // 
            // emptySpaceItem2
            // 
            this.emptySpaceItem2.AllowHotTrack = false;
            this.emptySpaceItem2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.emptySpaceItem2.Name = "emptySpaceItem2";
            this.emptySpaceItem2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(278, 407);
            this.emptySpaceItem2.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            // 
            // layoutControlItem1
            // 
            this.layoutControlItem1.Control = this.lblWelcome;
            this.layoutControlItem1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(278, 58);
            this.layoutControlItem1.Name = "layoutControlItem1";
            this.layoutControlItem1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 79);
            this.layoutControlItem1.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            this.layoutControlItem1.TextVisible = false;
            // 
            // emptySpaceItem3
            // 
            this.emptySpaceItem3.AllowHotTrack = false;
            this.emptySpaceItem3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(278, 350);
            this.emptySpaceItem3.MinSize = new System.Drawing.Size(104, 24);
            this.emptySpaceItem3.Name = "emptySpaceItem3";
            this.emptySpaceItem3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 57);
            this.emptySpaceItem3.SizeConstraintsType = DevExpress.XtraLayout.SizeConstraintsType.Custom;
            this.emptySpaceItem3.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            // 
            // emptySpaceItem4
            // 
            this.emptySpaceItem4.AllowHotTrack = false;
            this.emptySpaceItem4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(278, 0);
            this.emptySpaceItem4.Name = "emptySpaceItem4";
            this.emptySpaceItem4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 58);
            this.emptySpaceItem4.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            // 
            // emptySpaceItem5
            // 
            this.emptySpaceItem5.AllowHotTrack = false;
            this.emptySpaceItem5.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(278, 137);
            this.emptySpaceItem5.Name = "emptySpaceItem5";
            this.emptySpaceItem5.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(400, 54);
            this.emptySpaceItem5.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            // 
            // layoutControlItem2
            // 
            this.layoutControlItem2.Control = this.lblAppointment;
            this.layoutControlItem2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(343, 191);
            this.layoutControlItem2.Name = "layoutControlItem2";
            this.layoutControlItem2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(335, 53);
            this.layoutControlItem2.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            this.layoutControlItem2.TextVisible = false;
            // 
            // emptySpaceItem6
            // 
            this.emptySpaceItem6.AllowHotTrack = false;
            this.emptySpaceItem6.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(278, 191);
            this.emptySpaceItem6.Name = "emptySpaceItem6";
            this.emptySpaceItem6.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(65, 159);
            this.emptySpaceItem6.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            // 
            // layoutControlItem4
            // 
            this.layoutControlItem4.Control = this.lblNoAppointment;
            this.layoutControlItem4.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(343, 244);
            this.layoutControlItem4.Name = "layoutControlItem4";
            this.layoutControlItem4.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(335, 53);
            this.layoutControlItem4.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            this.layoutControlItem4.TextVisible = false;
            // 
            // layoutControlItem3
            // 
            this.layoutControlItem3.Control = this.lblPickupRepair;
            this.layoutControlItem3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(343, 297);
            this.layoutControlItem3.Name = "layoutControlItem3";
            this.layoutControlItem3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(335, 53);
            this.layoutControlItem3.TextSize = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 0);
            this.layoutControlItem3.TextVisible = false;
            // 
            // Welcome
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(1131, 427);
            this.Controls.Add(this.layoutCtrlMain);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Name = "Welcome";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.WindowState = System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState.Maximized;
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.Welcome_Load);
            this.Shown += new System.EventHandler(this.Welcome_Shown);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutCtrlMain)).EndInit();
            this.layoutCtrlMain.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.layoutCtrlMain.PerformLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutMain)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem2)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem1)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem3)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem4)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem5)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem2)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.emptySpaceItem6)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem4)).EndInit();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutControlItem3)).EndInit();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControl layoutCtrlMain;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlGroup layoutMain;
        private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl lblWelcome;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem layoutControlItem1;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem emptySpaceItem4;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem emptySpaceItem5;
        private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl lblAppointment;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem emptySpaceItem6;
        private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl lblPickupRepair;
        private DevExpress.XtraEditors.LabelControl lblNoAppointment;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem emptySpaceItem3;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem layoutControlItem2;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem layoutControlItem4;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.LayoutControlItem layoutControlItem3;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem emptySpaceItem1;
        private DevExpress.XtraLayout.EmptySpaceItem emptySpaceItem2;
    }
}
```

And here's the code page (.cs file):

```
    public partial class Welcome : BaseForm
    {
        public Welcome(int timeoutIntervalInSeconds, Controller controller) : base(timeoutIntervalInSeconds, controller)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            if (!_controller.IsDesignMode)
            {

            }

            _controller.SetDesignMode(layoutCtrlMain);
        }

        private void Welcome_FormClosing(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!_controller.IsDesignMode) return;
            _controller.SaveLayout(layoutCtrlMain, Enums.LayoutType.Welcome);
        }


        private void lblAppointment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _controller.OpenAppointments();
            Close();
        }

        private void lblNoAppointment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _controller.OpenAppointments();
            Close();
        }

        private void Welcome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _controller.LoadLayout(layoutCtrlMain, Enums.LayoutType.Welcome);

            layoutCtrlMain.LookAndFeel.Style = DevExpress.LookAndFeel.LookAndFeelStyle.Flat;
            layoutCtrlMain.LookAndFeel.UseDefaultLookAndFeel = false;
            layoutCtrlMain.OptionsView.ShareLookAndFeelWithChildren = false;
            layoutCtrlMain.OptionsView.EnableTransparentBackColor = true;
            layoutCtrlMain.Root.AppearanceGroup.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
            layoutCtrlMain.Root.AppearanceGroup.Options.UseBackColor = true;
            var sharepath = _controller.GetSharePath(Enums.LayoutType.Welcome);

            var backFile = Path.Combine(_controller.GetSharePath(LayoutType.Welcome), "background.png");
            if (File.Exists(backFile)) layoutCtrlMain.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(backFile);

            //throws them out of the main layoutgroup... 
            /*layoutControlItem4.RestoreFromCustomization();
            layoutControlItem3.RestoreFromCustomization();*/
        }

        private void Welcome_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadMenuDisplayed();
        }


        private void LoadMenuDisplayed()
        {
            //var sharepath = _controller.GetSharePath(LayoutType.Appointment);


            //((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutCtrlMain)).BeginInit();
            //flpMain.SuspendLayout();
            //flpMain.Controls.Clear();
            //layoutCtrlMain.SuspendLayout();


            //var itemFont = new Font("Arial", 18F, FontStyle.Bold);
            //var fontService = _controller.GetContainer().Resolve(typeof(ILayoutService), "") as ILayoutService;
            //if (fontService != null)
            //{
            //    var fontResponse = fontService.GetFontLayout(LayoutType.Appointment_Font_EmployeeNameButton);
            //    if (fontResponse.IsSuccess) itemFont = fontResponse.GetValue().Font;
            //}

            //var firstBtn = new MyHoverButton();

            //int counter = 0;
            //foreach (var item in response.Values)
            //{
            //    if (counter >= 20) break; //we only show 20 employees max
            //    var btn = new MyHoverButton();

            //    btn.TextLocation = TextLocation.Bottom;
            //    btn.ItemText = item.FullName;
            //    btn.ItemValue = item.ID;


            //    btn.ItemFont = itemFont;

            //    if (item.ID > 0)
            //    {

            //        var medwImg = Path.Combine(_controller.GetSharePath(LayoutType.Appointment), "Medewerkers", "contact_" + item.ID + ".jpg");
            //        if (File.Exists(medwImg))
            //        {
            //            btn.NormalImage = Image.FromFile(medwImg);
            //            //btn.HoverImage = Image.FromFile(medwImg);
            //        }
            //        else
            //        {

            //        }

            //    }

            //    btn.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None;

            //    //btn.Width = flpMain.Size.Width / 5;
            //    //btn.Height = flpMain.Size.Height / 4;
            //    btn.ItemClicked += Btn_Click;
            //    flpMain.Controls.Add(btn);
            //    counter++;
            //}


            //layoutCtrlMain.ResumeLayout();
            //flpMain.ResumeLayout();
            //((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.layoutCtrlMain)).EndInit();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with DevExpress so maybe I'm forgetting something somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not familiar with DevExpress so maybe I'm forgetting something
>   somewhere?

I believe that you did not forget anything, because new labels already visible in the designer. There must be a very simple key to this riddle.

Comment out this line in the Welcome_Load method:

```
 _controller.LoadLayout(layoutCtrlMain, Enums.LayoutType.Welcome);
```

If this helps, then newly added labels are not shown because the previously saved layout do not contain them.

To fix this problem and keep the _controller.LoadLayout code line uncommented, find the file where your _controller saves the layout and delete it.

Comment: Yes, that did it! The layout was loaded from somewhere else I believe... Commenting that line out made it able to change items on the screen :)